# Conditional expectation expressions

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, variance

I'm deriving the law of total variance and come across these two expression:

$$E[Y*E[Y|X]]$$
$$E[E[Y|X]*E[Y|X]]$$

$Y$ and $X$ are random variables.

Intuitively I think they should be equal, though I have no idea of how to prove it.

Comment: The idea would be to go straight from the definition

Comment: The following [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) may help.

Comment: I also find this link useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284932/prove-exy-eyexy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition I am familiar with is the following for $L^1$ functions, which is derived from the definition for $L^2$ functions using Hilbert Space. We necessarily need $E(Y|X)$ to be in $L^2$ for this problem.

Definition: Let $Y\in L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and $X$ a random variable. Then the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X$ is the (unique) random variable denoted by $E(Y|X) \in L^1(\Omega, \sigma(X), P)$ where
$$E(YZ) = E(E(Y|X)Z)$$
for all $Z$ bounded and $\sigma(X)$-measurable. Equivalently,
$$E(Yf(X)) = E(E(Y|X)f(X))$$
for all $f$ Borel.

Hence, from simply the definition, let $Z = E(Y|X)$ and you are done if $E(Y|X)$ is bounded. If not, consider $E(Y|X) \wedge n$, which is bounded. Then $E(Y|X) \wedge n \cdot E(Y|X) \to E^2(Y|X)$ and $|E(Y|X) \wedge n \cdot E(Y|X)| \leq E^2(Y|X) \in L^1$ so by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, 
$$E(E(Y|X)\cdot E(Y|X)\wedge n) \to E(E(Y|X)E(Y|X))$$
Similarly,
$YE(Y|X)\wedge n \to YE(Y|X)$ and $|YE(Y|X)\wedge n| \leq |YE(Y|X)| \in L^1$, so
$$E(YE(Y|X)\wedge n) \to E(YE(Y|X))$$
Since $E(Y|X) \wedge n$ bounded and $\sigma(X)$-measurable,
$$ E(E(Y|X)\cdot E(Y|X)\wedge n) = E(YE(Y|X)\wedge n)$$
so take limit and use the above two results.

Comment: So can I say actually those two expressions are equal to E[Y^2]?

Comment: I don't think so. My intuition says that's only true if Y is independent of X or Y is a function of X.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, I'm not clear how you derived the equality relation, just by definition?

Comment: Sure no problem. If $E(Y|X)$ is bounded, then since by definition it's $\sigma(X)$-measurable, it fits the criterion for $Z$ in the definition. So just replace $Z$ with it. If $E(Y|X)$ is not bounded, you need to use LDCT and definition on $E(Y|X)\wedge n$. I'll write more steps if the last part's not clear.